# MPMoviePlayerController.view isn't removed from superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
 NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
_moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
_moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
_moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
_moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[_moviePlayerController play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieIsOver:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)movieIsOver:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"movie is over");
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self.moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];//moviePlayerController is MPMoviePlayerController
}
```

When the movie plays to the end, I can't see "movie is over" log and the moviePlayerController.view isn't removed. I don't know why.

**EDIT:**
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification works well.I see the "movie is over" log.The problem is moviePlayerController.view isn't removed.

Comment: Please post the code used for initiating movie playback

Comment: How have you defined `moviePlayerController`? And in the notification callback, have you checked that the controller and view references are valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution:add

```
_moviePlayerController.fullscreen = NO;
```

before removing view from superview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding _moviePlayerController.view as subview

```
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
```

you can present _moviePlayerController just like this :

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: _moviePlayerController];
```

and in movieIsOver method you simply dismiss

```
[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
```

I hope its help